# Compare two lists in Python on equality and positioning

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a playable version of the classic game [Mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)) as a hobby project and I need to be able to compare two lists of strings (one being the guess and the other being the code) and get the number and color of "pegs" that should be displayed as feedback.

Essentially, for two pegs of the same color and same position, a red peg is displayed. For two pegs of the same color with different positions, a white peg is displayed. However, a white peg must match two specific pegs (e.g. Guess = [Green, Green, Green, Blue], Code = [Yellow, Yellow, Green, Green] would result in one red and one white peg being displayed).

I have found numerous posts about comparison on just position or just equality, but I need an algorithm that takes both into account. Here is my code so far:

```py
def getResponse(guess, code):
    pegs = []
    usedIndices = []
    usedCodeIndices = []
    for x in range(len(guess)):
        if guess[x] == code[x]:
            usedIndices.append(x)
            usedCodeIndices.append(x)
            pegs.append("red")
        elif guess[x] in code and x not in usedIndices:
            usedIndices.append(x)
            usedCodeIndices.append(code.index(guess[x]))
            pegs.append("white")
    return pegs
```

This code works well for red pegs, but will not recognize duplicates and display too many white pegs (e.g. Guess = [Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue], Code = [Blue, Red, Blue, White] would result in two red pegs and two white pegs being displayed, even though only two red should show.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: use `zip` function

Comment: `for i, in zip (list_a, list_b): `, you can access same index element in single loop from both lists.

Comment: @KlausD. See the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip to compute the positional matches and Counter for the overall color matching.  Then subtract the position match count from the color match count:

```
guess = ["R","R","B","W","Y"]
code  = ["R","G","B","R","Y"]

from collections import Counter
positionMatches = sum(a==b for a,b in zip(guess,code))
colorMatches    = len(code) - sum((Counter(code)-Counter(guess)).values())
colorMatches   -= positionMatches

print(positionMatches,colorMatches) # 3 1
```